# Divide a range in multiple steps, by using a sine-ease-in-out distribution

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm measuring a precise amount of increments (defined by *steps*), by linearly dividing a range with a minimum value (0 - implicit) and a maximum value (100 - explicit).

```js
const steps = 10;
const max = 100;

for (let step = 0; i < steps; step++) {
  console.log(((max * (step + 1)) / steps));
}

// 10
// 20
// 30
// 40
// 50
// 60
// 70
// 80
// 90
// 100
```

The example above works well for a **linear** distribution. How can I edit the script above to add a **sine-ease-in-out** one?